# Cannot assign property for a record in one array to a record in another array

Tags: arrays

I have two object arrays:

```
​
0: {…}
​​
count: 666
​​
id: "todo"
​​
maxEstimate: 0
​​
name: "To do"
​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​
1: {…}
​​
count: 666
​​
id: "in_progress"
​​
maxEstimate: 0
​​
name: "In progress"
```

and the other...

```
{…}
​
5f9d0e9c27425dc184aa67f2: 2
​
done: 3
​
in_progress: 11
​
todo: 21
​
<prototype>: Object { … }
```

Am trying to add the quantity from each element in the second array to the relevant entry in the first array ***(eg. add 11 from `in_progress` in the second array as a property count to record 1 in the first array)***.

I have no idea how to do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out using nestled forEach calls:

```
bob.forEach(function (issuetypes) {
      var x = issuetypes.id

      marg.forEach(function (issueitems) {
        if(issueitems.status == issuetypes.id){
         issuetypes.count = issuetypes.count + 1
        }
      });

    });
```